# How can I fill this pyramid like this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

How can I fill this pyramid like this picture? (with GeoSpacW)
[image]

I tried (with GeoGebra)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.5165217391304349,-3.515177065767286) rectangle (8.983478260869564,5.484822934232715);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (0.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (2.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (8.,0.)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (6.,-3.)-- (2.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (2.,-3.)-- (0.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.,0.)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.,0.)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663)-- (1.,-1.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (1.,-1.5);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (4.,-3.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (2.4,-1.2);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873)-- (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663)-- (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122)-- (4.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873)-- (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122);
\draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.12826086956521748,-0.25210792580101227) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (8.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (8.25,0.15) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=black] (6.,-3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (6.0260869565217385,-3.2116357504215856) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.,-3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.928695652173913,-3.2116357504215856) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.978260869565217,4.877740303541315) node {$S$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.,-1.5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.8,-1.7242833052276565) node {$M$};
\draw [fill=black] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (5.018260869565217,2.6) node {$N$};
\draw [fill=black] (4.,-3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.944347826086956,-3.226812816188871) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.4,-1.2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.399565217391304,-1.45) node {$O$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.320072463768116,-0.2224564362001124) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.250869565217391,-0.5101180438448571) node {$I$};
\draw [fill=black] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.2186956521739129,1.0379426644182121) node {$G$};
\draw [fill=black] (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (5.5,-1.5118043844856666) node {$F$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and got
[image]

Comment: I assume the picture represents a pyramid that has been cut by a plane going through the points EFNGM, correct?

Comment: @Werner Yes. Correct.

Comment: Would it be ok to use a transparent color (fill) instead of a pattern?  It would sure be easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `coordinates` where geogebra define vertices (`circle (1.5pt)`), like

```
\draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (A);
```

and fill the desired closed area with your preferred pattern

```
\path[pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red] (G)--(M)--(E)--(F)--(N)--cycle;
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.5165217391304349,-3.515177065767286) rectangle (8.983478260869564,5.484822934232715);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (0.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (2.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (8.,0.)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (6.,-3.)-- (2.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (2.,-3.)-- (0.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.,0.)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.,0.)-- (6.,-3.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663)-- (1.,-1.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (1.,-1.5);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (8.,0.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (4.,-3.);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326)-- (2.4,-1.2);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873)-- (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663)-- (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122)-- (4.,-3.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.,-1.5)-- (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873);
\draw [dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873)-- (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122);
\draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (A);
\draw[color=black] (-0.12826086956521748,-0.25210792580101227) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (8.,0.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (B);
\draw[color=black] (8.25,0.15) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=black] (6.,-3.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (C);
\draw[color=black] (6.0260869565217385,-3.2116357504215856) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.,-3.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (D);
\draw[color=black] (1.928695652173913,-3.2116357504215856) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.9204347826086954,4.665261382799326) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (S);
\draw[color=black] (1.978260869565217,4.877740303541315) node {$S$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.,-1.5) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (M);
\draw[color=black] (0.8,-1.7242833052276565) node {$M$};
\draw [fill=black] (4.960217391304347,2.332630691399663) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (N);
\draw[color=black] (5.018260869565217,2.6) node {$N$};
\draw [fill=black] (4.,-3.) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (E);
\draw[color=black] (3.944347826086956,-3.226812816188871) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.4,-1.2) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (O);
\draw[color=black] (2.399565217391304,-1.45) node {$O$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.320072463768116,-0.2224564362001124) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (I);
\draw[color=black] (2.250869565217391,-0.5101180438448571) node {$I$};
\draw [fill=black] (0.3200724637681158,0.7775435637998873) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (G);
\draw[color=black] (0.2186956521739129,1.0379426644182121) node {$G$};
\draw [fill=black] (5.320072463768115,-1.7224564362001122) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (F);
\draw[color=black] (5.5,-1.5118043844856666) node {$F$};
\path[pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red] (G)--(M)--(E)--(F)--(N)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: How can I chose style of segments MN and GN are dash?

Comment: How can I chose style of segments ME and GN are dash?

Comment: @minthao_2011   If you use `\path[pattern=...` instead of `\draw[red, pattern ...` the area border is not drawn and original black dashed or solid lines are not covered.

Comment: I did. But I could not get style of segments ME and GN are dash.

Comment: @minthao_2011      I've updated the code ans resulting figure. In code I've only changed third last line as in my previous comment. As you can see ME and GN are dashed lines.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `tkz-euclide`
My code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dotted}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,
8/0/B,
6/-3/C,
2/-3/D,
1/5/S}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,D)                      \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDefMidPoint(S,B)                      \tkzGetPoint{N}
\tkzDefMidPoint(D,C)                      \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(M,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzInterLL(M,N)(S,O) \tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through I](A,C)
 \tkzGetPoint{d}
\tkzInterLL(d,I)(S,C) \tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzInterLL(d,I)(S,A) \tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C,I,F)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D,M,G)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](S)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](O,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[above,right](N)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,C,D,S,M,N,O,I,F,G,E)
\tkzDrawSegments[hidden](A,B A,C M,N M,B S,O G,F M,E G,N)
\tkzDrawSegments(B,C C,D D,A S,A S,B S,C S,D S,M G,M E,F F,N)
\tkzFillPolygon[pattern color=red, pattern=vertical lines](G,M,E,F,N)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]